# Django - post request from simple rest client not received as json

Tags: django

I am using this chrome app, [simple rest client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-rest-client/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb) 
to test post requests.

I added data in the data field:

```
'{"a": "a1a1", "b": "b1b1"}'
```

I tested two headers in the header fields:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Type: application/json
```

But both headers failed, output in Django:

```
ipdb> request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'\'{"a": "a1a1", "b": "b1b1"}\'': [u'']}>
```

But if use python requests, it is working with below output:

```
ipdb> request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'a': [u'a1a1'], u'b': [u'b1b1']}>

ipdb> request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

How can I make it work with simple rest client ?

Comment: You showed yourself that the problem seems to be related to Simple rest client, not to Django :) I think You should edit tags or post your question on a more specialised forum where people are skilled with Simple rest client.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as your rest client is, it seems too simple. Try [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)